# Is $Y = \{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\} \cup \{(x,y):(x-2)^2+y^2=1\}$ homeomorphic to an interval?

Tags: general-topology

In an exercise I'm asked the following question:

> Is $Y = \{(x,y):x^2+y^2=1\} \cup \{(x,y):(x-2)^2+y^2=1\}$ homeomorphic to an interval?

To put this into context, this question is asked after the book introduced the following proposition:

> Let $f: (X,\tau) \to (Y,\tau_1)$ be a homeomorphism. Let $a \in X$, so that $X\setminus \{a\}$ is a subspace of $X$ with induced topology $\tau_2$. Also $Y\setminus \{f(a)\}$ is a subspace of $Y$ with induced topology $\tau_3$. Then we have that:
> $$(X\setminus\{a\},\tau_2) \cong (Y\setminus \{f(a)\},\tau_3)$$

---

So I think we are supposed to use this to solve the problem. This was my approach:

#### My approach:

First I made a plot of the set $Y$ to help visualize the set:

[image]

Let $S$ be an interval. Then $S$ is homeomorphic to one of the following:

1. $\{0\}$
2. $]0,1[$
3. $[0,1[$
4. $[0,1]$

---

1. 

Clearly $Y \nsim \{0\}$. This means that $Y \not \cong \{0\}$

---

2. 

Let's assume that $Y \cong ]0,1[$. Then, because of the proposition we have that:

$Y\setminus\{(-1,0)\} \cong \ ]0,1[\  \setminus \{a\}$, for some value of $a \in ]0,1[$.

We have that $]0,1[\  \setminus \{a\}$ is disconnected, but $Y\setminus\{(-1,0)\}$ is connected. So we have a contradiction. Meaning that $Y \not \cong ]0,1[$

---

3. 

Here I did the same that I did in (2.) but twice:

Let's assume that $Y \cong [0,1[$

Then: $Y\setminus\{(-1,0)\} \cong \ [0,1[\  \setminus \{a\}$, for some value of $a \in [0,1[$.

If $a \neq 0$ then we are done because $[0,1[\  \setminus \{a\}$ would be disconnected.

If $a = 0$, then we do the same again: $$Y\setminus\{(-1,0),(3,0)\} \cong \ [0,1[\  \setminus \{0,b\}$$

Clearly $[0,1[\  \setminus \{0,b\} = ]0,1[ \setminus \{b\}$ is disconnected and $Y\setminus\{(-1,0),(3,0)\}$ is connected. This is a contradiction, thus $Y \not \cong [0,1[$

---

4. 

The problem and the heart of this post comes when trying to prove this part.

Let's assume that $Y \cong [0,1]$.

If we do this two times like we did in the previous part we'll end up with:

$$Y\setminus\{(-1,0),(3,0)\} \cong \ [0,1]\  \setminus \{a,b\}$$

Where $\{a,b\} = \{0,1\}$, because if not, then the interval would already be disconnected and the proof ended. To make $[0,1]\  \setminus \{0,1\}$ disconnected we just need to add one extra "hole". But the problem is that if we add one extra hole to the set $Y$ as well, the set becomes disconnected, and that does not prove anything.

In the set $Y$ if two "holes" are in the same circle, then it creates one disconnected part. So how can I put "3" in the set $Y$ in order for it to still be connected? If this is not possible, how do I prove this? Or is indeed $Y \cong [0,1]$?

Comment: The fundamental groups of homeomorphic spaces are isomorphic (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FundamentalGroup.html), and because [0,1] has the trivial fundamental group, and Y has the free group on two letters as its fundamental group, $Y \not \equiv [0,1]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you now remove the origin from $Y\setminus\{\langle -1,0\rangle,\langle 3,0\rangle\}$, you get four pieces. Can you get four pieces by removing a point from the open interval $(0,1)$?

Comment: You mean remove the point where the circles intersect?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Yes I see. Why would that mean that hey are not homeomorphic then? The notes I'm following don't have that

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães: You’ve already shown that if they are homeomorphic, then $Y\setminus\{\langle -1,0\rangle,\langle 3,0\rangle\}$ must be homeomorphic to $(0,1)$. The argument that I just suggested shows that this is not the case, so $Y$ cannot be homeormorphic to $[0,1]$.

Comment: So if two spaces are homeomorphic, if we remove $a$ from the first one, and $f(a)$ from the second, then the number of connected parts must allays match?

Comment: Yes. Because homeomorphisms are bicontinuous, and connectedness is preserved by continuous transform, there must be a bijection between connected components in the domain and codomain.